# Someone who lends usurious money and their action

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, verbs

What do you call a person who achieves lots of money without working, just sitting at home lending people money with the agreement that they will pay him/her back a very much larger amount of money in a specific time in a written or verbal agreement?

Meanwhile, how shall I allude to such action in normal English? (Please note that aside from a true person, a legal entity like: banks, government related organizations etc. can do the same thing.)
Does it sound natural to say: **"They offer usury**"?

Answer (score 1):

Formally a "usurer", more colloquially a "loan shark". These terms imply illegal or at least highly immoral actions.  "Usuary" has a religious connotation, and is not often seen outside of that context.  Traditionally Christians were forbidden by their religion to charge interest on a loan. You could use "moneylender" with less explicit negative meaning.

As a verb, or at least a gerund, you can use "loansharking".

If you want to suggest something positive: "Venture capitalist" or "investor" are positive

Comment: Excellent. Just not to be forgotten @James K, please tell me about the plausible verb of this sense too. :)

Comment: I can think of a few others, but I suspect that I might get in trouble for posting ethnic slurs if I posted them.

Comment: It would not be you getting into trouble, it would be the poor learner who might use the term unaware.

Comment: Thank you @nick012000 and JamesK. I didin't get the point unfortunately. Is there something wrong with the terms ethnically. Do they aound strange in some cultures? Are they considered as too religious terms that we should avoid using them? Please explain that to me.

Comment: Meanwhile @JamesK, you has not mentioned the proper verb to that yet. Does **"offer usury"** work? Or the accceptable for would be something like you used? I mean: **"offer usurious rates of interest"**.

Comment: @A-friend The terms that James K offered were fine. The terms I was thinking of were things like “jewing”, “kiking”, and “gyping”, none of which should be used carelessly because they’re ethnic slurs against the Jewish and Romani (gypsy) peoples.

Comment: What a suphistucated topic is language @nick012000 specially these cultural and belief-dependant parts. However, thank you very much for informing me about it.

Comment: @A-friend I wouldn’t say that they’re culturally dependent- they’re ethnic slurs because they’re references to stereotypes of Jews as greedy misers, and Romani as dishonest thieves.

Comment: I see @nick012000, but it was the point regarding the cultural gap! In our language, we use so similar terms (at least in informal language) without hesitation or trying to be picky towards words to avoid being vulgar or offensive. [I'm not at all about some nations or religious categories; I'm more about the way we look at choosing a particular term/word/etc.]